# Facebook App: post to page now failing with "An unknown error has occurred" / OAuthException

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I have an application that posts daily statuses to a Page wall, the statuses are posted as the application (see http://facebook.com/fragrantheart). My app is "Fragrant Heart Daily Meditations" and as you can see has been quite happily posting away for many years now.
However, now, when it posts, I get the error:

```
 [message] => An unknown error has occurred.
 [type] => OAuthException
 [code] => 1
```

Here is my code that runs on the server (PHP api):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'=>'148279321865482', 'secret'=>'XXXXXX', 'cookie'=>false));
$target_id = '124924677541618'; // Fragrant Heart Meditation Page
$facebook->api("/{$target_id}/feed", 'POST', array('message'=>$msg));
```

From what I've read, there is NO access_token required, as the page has granted my app the publish_stream permission.

**What has changed recently that would cause this error? The code has not changed.**

I have also tried the server-side authentication flow to obtain an access token, and when running that token through the debugger I get:

```
App ID:  148279321865482 : Fragrant Heart Daily Meditations
User ID: 100001170589484 : Elisabeth Blaikie
Issued:  1289470487 (over a year ago)
Expires: Never
Valid:   True
Origin:  Web
Scopes:  create_note manage_pages offline_access photo_upload publish_actions publish_stream share_item status_update video_upload
```

but when using the access token like this: (obviously, YYYYYYY is replaced with the actual token):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'=>'148279321865482', 'secret'=>'XXXXXX', 'cookie'=>false));
$target_id = '124924677541618'; // Fragrant Heart Meditation Page
$facebook->api("/{$target_id}/feed", 'POST', array('message'=>$msg, 'access_token'=>'YYYYYYY'));
```

I get the error:

```
[message] => Invalid OAuth access token.
[type] => OAuthException
[code] => 190
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Haha - so the original issue was actually the access_token missing; however when I pasted the access_code in to my code I had mis-copied my access key; hence the "Invalid OAuth access token". D'Oh!

So for anyone else in the same situation (automatically posting to your own page from a PHP server), the correct code is

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'=>'YOUR APP ID', 'secret'=>'YOUR APP SECRET', 'cookie'=>false));
$target_id = 'YOUR PAGE ID'; 
$facebook->api("/{$target_id}/feed", 'POST', array('message'=>'YOUR MESSAGE', 'access_token'=>'YYYYYYY'));
```

To get a permanent access token, follow the steps in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/ specifically steps 1 and 4:

Sign in as the owner of the page you want to post to. Go to

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
   &scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES
   &state=SOME_ARBITRARY_BUT_UNIQUE_STRING
```

COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES should be **publish_stream**, and any other perms you need.
Accept the request, which will redirect back to YOUR_REDIRECT_URI (which must be the same domain as in your app settings)
Copy the CODE from the redirect URI and go to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
   &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
   &code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK
```

The access token will be in the body of the page.